# writing an each & map method - array/ object iteration with object.prototype.toString

Tags: functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash, higher-order-functions

### Trying to re-write `each()` & `map()`

this should be just like the native `forEach`, or the underscore or lodash `_.each` method. It should take an array or an object. I've heard conflicting things about whether or not to  use `Array.isArray` or `instanceof` to determine if the collection passed in is an object or an array, and my current understanding is that using this `object.prototype.toString` thing is the best way. Maybe I'm completely wrong. I've been wacking away at this for hours, and would appreciate any suggestions or input at all.

My function seems to be okay, but it never makes any changes on any array or object I give it. If it is an object, I want to alter the values, not the property name. Sorry if my comments are annoyingly redundant. Please help.

### `TgEach( collection, callback )`

Here are some stupid arrays and objects. For each, I am expecting the collection to be modified in place. Am I mistaken?

```js
var tgObj = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };
var tgArr = [ 1,2,3,4,5];

// I'm invoking it like 

TgEach( tgObj, function(n){ return n + 3 } );
TgEach( tgArr, function(n){ return n + 3 } );

// I give it a collection and a callback - adding three to each item. 

// I'm expecting `tgArr` to now equal `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and   
// `tgObj` to now equal `{ one: 4, two: 5, three: 6, four: 7, five: 8 };`

// But nothing ever happens... 
// Here's my function...

  var TgEach = function( collection, callback ){

  var dataStructure = 0;

   (function ObjectOrArray( collection ){
     if ( {}.toString.call( collection ) === "[object Array]" ){
       dataStructure += 1;
     }
     else if ( {}.toString.call( collection ) === "[object Object]" ){
       dataStructure += 2;
     }
   })();

  if ( dataStructure === 1 ){
    for ( var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++ ){
      callback( collection[i] );
   }
  else ( dataStructure === 2 ){
    for ( var key in collection ){
      callback( collection[key] );
  }
 }  
};
```

for the callback function, let's say I want to add 3. So for this...

```
TgEach( tgObj, function(n){ return n + 3 } );
TgEach( tgArr, function(n){ return n + 3 } );
```

I'm expecting `tgArr` to now equal `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and
`tgObj` to now equal 
`{ one: 4, two: 5, three: 6, four: 7, five: 8 };`

But nothing ever happens...

### `TgMap( collection, callback )`

map relies on each, so this has got me all stressed

my map looks like this..

```
var map = function( collection, callback ){
  var result = [];

  each( collection, function(item){
    result.push( callback( collection[item] ) );
  });

  return result;
}
```

What the hell am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you call the callback you are not assigning the result to anything. Try something like `collection[key] = callback(collection[key])`